# How to auto start/stop tether if wifi is unavailable/available?

Tags: tethering

I use my Galaxy S as a wifi tether hotspot for my tablet and laptop, so tethering is always on (I have extended battery so it's ok). But if my phone is in the area where I have wifi internet (for example, at home) I don't need it to act as hotspot and want it to stop tethering and connect wifi. Is there a way to automatically start tethering if no wifi is available and stop it / connect wifi if wifi is available for long enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so e.g. with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), adapting the [Wifi Tether Profile](http://tasker.wikidot.com/wifi-tether) described in the Tasker Wiki -- provided your phone is rooted:

### Requirements

- rooted device
- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)
- <del>[Locale Execute Plug-In](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.elmicha.app.LocaleExecute)</del> (no longer available -- but most likely no longer needed, either)
- [Wireless Tether for Root Users](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.tether)

### Tasker-Tasks

- **Tether-On:**
  <del>Plugin -> Execute</del> Script -> Run Shell `/data/data/android.tether/tether start 1`, check "Use Root"
  <sup>(with the *Locale Execute Plugin*, prefix the command with an `!` to mark it as "root command")</sup>
- **Tether-Off:**
  <del>Plugin -> Execute</del> Script -> Run Shell `/data/data/android.tether/tether stop 1`
  <sup>(with the *Locale Execute Plugin*, prefix the command with an `!` to mark it as "root command")</sup>

### Tasker-Profiles

You now can attach these tasks to any condition, such as e.g. "Wifi Near" with your networks name. You can also add things like "Wifi On" / "Wifi off" to above tasks to customize.

Detailed descriptions can be found in the linked Wiki.

Comment: Locale Execute Plug-In is dead